# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. >

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
>   in android 
>   AndroidManifest.xml

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ator.arian"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
}
```

Comment: Logs & AndroidManifest code would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check all Resource files in **values** [color,string,dimen,style,etc], check is there any **undesirable** attribute name is present which should **not be present** in that file. 
Do **correction** in attribute name. 
Clean the project.